# Error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.” in MySql/net connector

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm newbie MVC (C#). When I query data from `item_master` and `item_lookup_type`.

I have some error:

> "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection
>   which must be closed first" at line  var ILU =
>   db.itemlookuptypes.Find(u.ItemLookUpID);

My Code:

```
public List<ItemMasterView> GetAllItemLists()
{
    List<ItemMasterView> ItemViews = new List<ItemMasterView>();

    using (packinglistEntities db = new packinglistEntities())
    {
        ItemMasterView IMV;
        var items = db.itemmasters.ToList();

        foreach (itemmaster u in db.itemmasters)
        {
            IMV = new ItemMasterView();
            IMV.ItemID = u.ItemID;
            IMV.ItemName = u.ItemName;
            IMV.ItemDesc = u.ItemDesc;

            IMV.Weight = u.Weight;
            IMV.Height = u.Height;
            IMV.Width = u.Width;
            IMV.StartDate = IMV.StartDate;
            IMV.EndDate = IMV.EndDate;

            var ILU = db.itemlookuptypes.Find(u.ItemLookUpID);

            if (ILU != null)
            {
                IMV.Name = ILU.Name;
            }

            /*IMV.Name = "JM";*/

            ItemViews.Add(IMV);
        }
    }

    return ItemViews;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `db.itemmasters`and not the `items` in the foreach?

Comment: Thank you.I revised my code with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

@Jérémie Bertrand  your suggestion is best answer.

I revised line from:

```
var items = db.itemmasters.ToList();
foreach (itemmaster u in db.itemmasters)
```

to:

```
var items = db.itemmasters.ToList();
foreach (itemmaster u in items)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your items variable. That should allow the original reader to close.